# When @including a mixin, it refers to a previously passed variable

Tags: css, sass

So I defined this mixin.

```
@mixin bgReveal($color) {
  animation-name: bgReveal;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  @keyframes bgReveal {
    0% {background: transparent;}
    100% {background: $color;}
  }
}
```

Now when I do this

```
.profile-card {
    @include bgReveal($color1);
}

.profile-mail {
    @include bgReveal($color2);
}
```

`profile-card` and `profile-mail` component are both having its background set to `color2`. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems problem is in animations name:

```
@keyframes bgReveal {
    0% {background: transparent;}
    100% {background: $color;}
  }
```

You've created the same animation twice (cause you've included the mixin twice), with the same name, but with different background color. Per CSS rules if you have 2 same properties, the last one will be active. So if you have 2 keyframes animations with the same name, only last one will be applied.

If you simply pass a unique animation name in your mixin, it will work properly!

```
@mixin bgReveal($color, $anim-name) {
  animation-name: $anim-name;
  animation-duration: 350ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

  @keyframes #{$anim-name} {
    0% {background: transparent;}
    100% {background: $color;}
  }
}

.profile-card {
    @include bgReveal($color1, redAnim);
}

.profile-mail {
    @include bgReveal($color2, greenAnim);
}
```

Check the [working codepen snippet](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/0a3034c75cfcac0ac8d0c0da071c8757).

Comment: Thank you, this makes so much sense!